# PHP line return use. Need to use /r to display text in the same place in combination with a textbox

Tags: php, textbox, return, sleep

I am trying to recieve input from a textbox.  Then on the same page it writes words and copies over them on the same line with the use of \r.

I can successfully copy text on the same line by itself but when combined with a textbox it does not work.

The first section of code works, but does not work when combined with a textbox.

This works:

```
echo "Validating\r";
sleep(1);
echo "Validated\r";
sleep(1);
echo 'Sending 7 BTC to dfsadfdsafasdfsda';
```

However when combined with a form it does not use \r correctly and the last line of text is all placed on one line one after another.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <strong>Address: *</strong> <input type="text"  name="code">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
        $code = htmlentities($_POST['code']);
        echo "Validating\r";
        sleep(1);
        echo "Validated\r";
        sleep(1);
        echo 'Sending 7 BTC to ' .$code. '<br>';
    }    
?>
```

This results in the following line:
Validating Validated Sending 7 BTC to sdafsdfasfsdafa

Instead it should show
Validating - pause one second - erase the line - 
show Validated - pause one second - erase the line -
show Sending 7 BTC to sdafsdfasfsdafa

How can I successfully use /r to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PHP_EOL constant. like: `echo "Validating".PHP_EOL`  See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php for more information.

Another thing you could try is using nl2br(). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php.

Comment: Yah  - I am attempting to return to the begining of the line and overwrite the text. I dont want to start a new line. .

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case, I'd use jquery and ajax to do what you're doing.  This would have the added benefit of being able to eliminate the sleep function calls by using a callback function when it's done.  And jquery will happily overwrite text for you.  Though you probably would have to put it in a div first.
Here's some more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/